# Django Not working properly in visual studio

Tags: python, django, visual-studio-code

This is my first post so please spare me with any mistake. I have been working with Python for 2 years as a student and now I wanted to use it to create web applications. But I found an error on my visual studio code. I used

```sh
python manage.py runserver hello
```

to run Django but it didn't worked.
It said,

> Directory Not found

I have installed Python and Django successfully and I can see the manage.py file in my folder but I am unable to run it. Please tell me how can I run it? I am attaching that thing-

```sh
python C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Atharwa\Atharwa coding\Web application programming\manage.py --version
```

> C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\python.exe:
> can't open file 'manage.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

But, I do have a file named manage.py. So, please tell me how can I run it?

Comment: The error possibly occurred because your visual studio code is opened in a directory which is one level up from the root directory of your django project. Is the `manage.py` file located as a file in the file explorer or within a directory when viewed from the file explorer in VS Code? If the later is your answer, then you should to run `cd <directory within which manage.py is located>` and then `python manage.py runserver`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried updating VS? It may also be a failure in the Django installation. Another solution can be making sure everything is in the correct directory.